# MongoDb Query db.<collectionname>.find()

Tags: mongodb

I have this Document for mongodb im working on.
The query i m running is showing no output even though there is
one field with score < 5

```
{
"address": {
"building": "1007",
"coord": [ -73.856077, 40.848447 ],
"street": "Morris Park Ave",
"zipcode": "10462"
},
"borough": "Bronx",
"cuisine": "Bakery",
"grades": [
{ "date": { "$date": 1393804800000 }, "grade": "A", "score": 2 },
{ "date": { "$date": 1378857600000 }, "grade": "A", "score": 6 },
{ "date": { "$date": 1358985600000 }, "grade": "A", "score": 10 },
{ "date": { "$date": 1322006400000 }, "grade": "A", "score": 9 },
{ "date": { "$date": 1299715200000 }, "grade": "B", "score": 14 }
],
"name": "Morris Park Bake Shop",
"restaurant_id": "30075445"
}

db.rest.find({grades : {"score":{$lt:5}}});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that your query isn't getting the expected result is that you're not quite using the correct syntax for querying a field in an embedded document. The correct syntax is

`db.rest.find({ "grades.score" : {$lt:5}})`

This syntax uses the dot notation to specify the path to the field in the embedded document that you are querying for.

The syntax you used means something a tad different. It queries for a document that has an embedded document which is an exact match to the document in your query rather than looking for a document that has an embedded document with a field in it that matches your search criteria.

To illustrate the difference, let's assume you also have the following document in the collection.

```
{
"address": {
"building": "1007",
"coord": [ -73.856077, 40.848447 ],
"street": "Morris Park Ave",
"zipcode": "10462"
},
"borough": "Bronx",
"cuisine": "Bakery",
"grades": [
 { "score": 2 },
 { "score": 6 },
 { "score": 10 },
 { "score": 9 },
 { "score": 14 }
```

],
  "name": "Morris Park Bake Shop",
  "restaurant_id": "30075445"
  }

If we now run the following query, it finds the second document, and *only* the second document:

`db.rest.find({grades : {"score":2}})`

This is because this type of query translates the embedded document you specified as the search criterion into its BSON representation and then looks for an exact match to the supplied document rather than apply the criterion you were looking for to every embedded document that has a 'score' field.
If run the query using the

Comment: Worked. Did'nt know that quotes do change the meaning.